# read rss feed c# with element extensions

Tags: c#, hyperlink, rss

I want to read some data from an rss feed. I use:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create([THE FEED URL]);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
// do what you want with the feed data
}
```

The problem is that it has no items. But it has two element extensions that contain all the items.
How can I extract that data? And how do I get custom fields out? When I try with a feed that has Items the only thing I can get out is Title, Description and Link and some more, but I want to get some custom attributes.

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title></title>
<link>...</link>
<description>List of enabled mobile telephones</description>
<telephones>...</telephones>
<subscriptions>...</subscriptions>
</channel>
</rss>
```

the telephones node contains a list of items.